# Segmentation fault (core dumped) below printf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int H, W, X, Y, cont=1, j=0, x, y;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &H, &W, &X, &Y);
    char matriz[H][W + 1];
    for(int i=0; i<H; i++){
        scanf("%s", matriz[i]);
    }
printf("%s", matriz[3]);
    while(j<4){
        while(1){
            y=y - 1;
            if(matriz[X][Y]==matriz[x][y])
             cont++;
            else
                break;
        }
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

hello I wanted to know why my code does not want to run that first printf, giving the error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and if I remove everything below printf it will work again

Comment: What inputs are you giving?

Comment: I don't think there are any guarantees that the code above the crashing line shall produce any output.

Answer (score 1):

`x` and `y` are not initialized so you are subject to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here when you give segmentation fault it means you are going out of the allocated storage for ((martiz[][])).
for example:

if we have an array names x[4],

then we want to print x[5],

you will receive segmentation fault.

So look at your Code and find the line that program going out of allocated space. otherwise, notice that you should initialize your data types when you define them.